# Enable Cuda in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use the CUDA-related function with OpenCV.

I am using OpenCV 2.4.9 with Cuda 6.0. **I have built the Visual Studio project with Cuda flag enabled.**
When I put the following line into my code:

```
int a =  gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();
```

then `a` is zero, so Cuda is not enabled.

What do I have to do to enable Cuda in my project?

Comment: are you using prebuilt binaries of opencv or are you recompiling opencv?

Comment: did the cmake report that it found cuda in the log after you configure the the build.  it should say "CUDA detected: 6.0"  at the top

Comment: Yes cmake says that it has found cuda 6.0. Then after that i Starter the visual Studio project that cmake made and built it in debug and release mode.

Comment: has nobody an idea what went wrong?